# Object is not instantiated for deep relationships in Codeigniter DataMapper ORM

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

From this example:

http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/getadvanced.html#Deep.Relationship.Include

You can see that it says: **At this time, deep relationships do not support instatiation.**.

So if we have some methods defined in the Group model, it still can't be used unless we manually collect the field data and instantiate the group object ourselves.

I am interested in why it's not supported, is this something very difficult to achieve for an ORM?

Also, I would very much like to know if there is any easy workaround or how you solved this problem.

Comment: @Lion Sorry about that. I haven't visited SO for a long time so I forgot about that rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instantiate related objects when you use include_related(), but you can not instantiate deep relations ( like include_related('groups/users/posts/comments') ), the code simply doesn't support it.

Remember that DataMapper has been around for quite a few years, and the current v1.x codebase still supports CodeIgniter 1.7. Which means it contains a fair amount of PHP4 legacy code.

I'm busy designing DataMapper v2, which will address this issue.

Comment: Thanks. Hope you've been recovered from illness :)